# Is there a way to set file pointers equal to each other in C?

Tags: c

For example, if I have

```
FILE *fp, *tfp;

fp = fopen (file, mode);

tfp = fp;
```

is this possible?

Comment: It's syntactically legal, so yes.

Comment: AS others said, yes, you can. But remember they're always _the same object_

Comment: Have you tried it, and did it work?  If it immediately failed, then it isn't possible.  If it succeeded, chances are good it is possible, unless you have evidence that it only succeeded by sheer luck.

Comment: The answer to that is pretty simple as you can see. It got me wandering, though, if you wanted to, somehow, duplicate the "file descriptor" that you created with fopen(). That would be a totally different story.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and totally legal.

Both `fp` and `tfp` are pointers to a variable of type `FILE`
The statement `tfp = fp;` copies the address saved in fp into tfp. So, please keep in mind that you end up with two pointers to the same object.

You aren't duplicating the "object" created in the fopen() call at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that it possible. These are just pointers after all. You can have as many variables as you like containing the same pointer and nobody can tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. But the best way to learn is to try. Launch this code under debugger and check that this works as you expect.

Comment: Trial and error can be helpful but I would not describe it as the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer variable (FILE * fp) simply contains an address (a number). You can see it:

```
printf( "%p\n", fp );
```

So, assigning numbers of same type is perfectly legal.

Comment: To comply 100% with the Standard the pointer should be cast to `void*` type: `printf("%p\n", (void*)fp);`